# SQL Query - Filter with different type

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I'm very stuck to create my sql query. If someone can help me or advice me.

I have a group with an Arraycollection of Filters:

Group :

```
-------------------------
|   id  |     name      |
|------------------------
|    1  |    group1    |
|------------------------
|    2  |    group2    |
|------------------------
|    3  |    group3    |
|------------------------
|    4  |    group4    |
|------------------------
```

Filter :

```
------------------------------------
|   id  | group_id | Type| Value    |
|-----------------------------------
|    1  |    1     |  1  |  15      |
|------------------------------------
|    2  |    1     |  2  |  25-34   |
|------------------------------------
|    3  |    1     |  2  |  35-44   |
|------------------------------------
|    4  |    2     |  2  |  25-34   |
|------------------------------------
|    5  |    2     |  2  |  35-44   |
|------------------------------------
|    6  |    3     |  1  |  11      |
|------------------------------------
|    7  |    3     |  1  |  15      |
|------------------------------------
```

For example, I need to filter my group with those critere:

```
filter.type = 1 and filter.value = 11
filter.type = 2 and filter.value in ('25-34','35-44')
filter.group_id = null
```

The result must be :

```
-------------------------
|   id  |     name      |
|------------------------
|    2  |    group2    |
|------------------------
|    3  |    group3    |
|------------------------
|    4  |    group4    |
|------------------------
```

Group1 is not taken because the unique value for type=1 is different of 11. Group3 is taken because he has one result with the value=11 when type=1.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Have tries something like that :

```
SELECT *FROM group c0_
LEFT JOIN group_filter c1_ ON c0_.id = c1_.group_id
WHERE
    (
        c0_.public = '1' AND c0_.state = '4'
    ) AND(
        (
            c1_.id IN(
            SELECT
                c2_.id
            FROM
                group c3_,
                group_filter c2_
            WHERE
                (
                    c2_.id IN(
                    SELECT
                        c4_.id
                    FROM
                        group c5_,
                        group_filter c4_
                    WHERE
                        c4_.type = 1 AND c4_.value = 11
                )
                ) AND(
                    (
                        c2_.type = 2 AND c2_.value IN('18-24', '25-34')
                    )
                )
        )
        ) OR c1_.group_id IS NULL
    )
GROUP BY
    c0_.id
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: The answer seems simple, trying to use 'select distinct id from filter where (condition1) or (condition2)

Comment: Hi @Sphinx thank you for your answer but im using group By and it doesn't work. It's not simple, have try to create subquery to in first time filter by type =1 then type2 ... but it doesn't work.

Comment: If we have type=1 and value=11, we need to verify if type=2 exist and is in ('18-24', '25-34').

If we have an entry with type=1 and a value <>11, we don't take the type=2 with value in  ('18-24', '25-34').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from t_group INNER JOIN (
SELECT
    t_group.id as id ,
    GROUP_CONCAT(case 
        when t_filter.t_type=1 and t_filter.t_value='11' THEN 'A' 
        when t_filter.t_type=1 and t_filter.t_value<>'11' THEN 'B'
        when t_filter.t_type=2 and (t_filter.t_value ='25-34' or t_filter.t_value ='35-44') then 'C'
        when t_filter.group_id is null then 'D'
        else 'E'
    END) str
FROM
    t_group
LEFT JOIN t_filter ON t_group.id = t_filter.group_id
GROUP BY
    t_group.id) t ON t_group.id=t.id
where (LOCATE('B',t.str)=0 OR LOCATE('A',t.str)>0) AND LOCATE('E',t.str)=0
```

first,i query all the probably result,and contact to a string accroding to the group,then except the result i do not want

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for your answer. It seems working but i need to understand how that work. Can i ask you if i have question about your query please? Thanks again

Comment: if you have question,we can discuss together

Comment: Hi @John, Thanks a lot for your solution working very well. But i try to use queryBuilder but he don't want take me the innerJoin select. Do you have an alternative query to do the same thing that work with querybuilder?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe you can use the leftjoin and add " t.id is not null" on where

Answer (score 0):

If the table1 name is **Groups** and table2's **Filters** ,
For the result:

```
-------------------------
|   id  |     name      |
|------------------------
|    2  |    group2    |
|------------------------
|    3  |    group3    |
|------------------------
|    4  |    group4    |
|------------------------
```

the query will be:

```
SELECT g.id,g.name 
FROM groups AS g 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN filters AS f 
    ON f.group_id=g.id 
WHERE ( g.type IN(1,2) AND (g.value IN ('25-34','35-44') )  ) ;
```

Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. It doesn't work. That query take the Group1 and he shouldn't take it because he has an entry with type=1 but value<>11.

Comment: If i have an entry with type=1 the value must be 11 or i don't take it.
If i have not an entry with type=1, i check type=2.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand your criterias, below SQL works. *(please remove the comments in the SQL codes before try at your client)*

```
select distinct g1.id,  g1.name 
from groups g1 left join filters f1 on g1.id=f1.group_id
where 
        ( 
            f1.type=1 and f1.value=11 
            and exists (select 1 from filters f2 where f2.group_id=f1.group_id and f2.type=2 and f2.value in ('25-34','35-44'))
        )  #If type=1 and value=11, then must exists same group with type=2 and value in ('25-34', '35-44')
    or (
            f1.type=1 and f1.value<>11 
            and not exists (select 1 from filters f2 where f2.group_id=f1.group_id and f2.type=2 and f2.value in ('25-34','35-44'))
        )  #If type=1 and value=11, then doesn't allow same group exists type=2 and value in ('25-34','35-44')
    or not exists (select 1 from filters f2 where f2.group_id=f1.group_id and f2.type=1)
       #If not exists same group have type=1 (including null) then return true
```

Comment: Hi, Thank for yout answer.
Sometimes Type=1 can not exist too. I need to filter my group about each type if exist or not exist. So if i have a lot of type. Here 2 type we have 4 possibilities : 0=not exist and 1=exist

- Type1=0 | Type2=0
- Type1=0 | TYpe2=1
- Type1=1 | Type2=0
- Type1=1 | Type2=1

The select begin very complex if i have more types. So maybe the solution of @railondi using Group_Concat is better solution ?